# Javascript - Autocomplete on focus textfield

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I have this code for autocomplete after another textfield has been compiled. Problem it is that this autocomplete works only after is inserted 1 letter, i want to show autocomplete when text field is focus. I tried put event focus too, but it doesn't do any call to server. How can i show autocomplete results when user just click/focus on textfield?

```
 $("#localitaTextBox").autocomplete
    ({
    source: function (request, responce) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetAllLocalitaJson", "Spedizione")',
        method: "post",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ localita: request.term, cap: $("#capTextBox").val() }),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            responce($.map(data.Result, function (item)
            {
                return {
                    label: item.Localita + ", " + item.CAP,
                    value: item.Localita,
                    id: item.CAP,
                };
            }))
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
});
        },
    select: function (e, ui)
    {
        $("#capTextBox").val(ui.item.id);
        compileProvCode();
        code = compileStatoCode();
       // compileNation(code);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to pass an option minLenght as follow:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0 // this one!
});
```

by default is 1 but I believe 0 will work for you.

I also believe that on focus shouldn't be making calls to the server just because when you make a call this will look for * (everything) without any restriction and can be a bad UX. good luck!

edit:
Try this, is a bit hacky and definitely shouldn't be this way but I think they have a bug? They are actually expecting a keypress down

```
$("#localitaTextBox").on("focus", function() {
$(this).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: availableTags
});
$(this).trigger("keydown"); //magic line ?
```

});